# Which crops provide the most daily profit?

Tags: stardew-valley

I'm trying to optimize the money I can make each season, so I can spend the late game mining, fishing, and other fun things there are to do in the valley!

What crops provide the most daily profit?

By daily profit, I mean profit per day it needs to grow.

Edit: Accepted Timmy Jim answer because exactly answer the question, but you might want to look out Mage Xy's. The tools he proposed are really nice.

Comment: How far in the game are you? You don't really need to wait until "late game" to mine, fish, and do other things. Farming is on of the least time-consuming activities once you get sprinklers.

Comment: I'm at the end of the first summer, I don't have sprinklers yet.

Comment: Do you have access to preserves jars and kegs?

Comment: As a last mention, wealth has nothing to do with having time to explore the game. I think you're looking at this from the wrong perspective.

Comment: It's also worth noting that some higher value crops that can only be grown in certain seasons will eventually be able to be grown in the greenhouse year round. Also that certain crops like berries drop various amounts, so the number is more of an average for them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Following [this guide](http://www.carlsguides.com/stardewvalley/farming/crops.php), the following crops provide the most daily profit:

**Spring**

- Strawberries at $11.67 a day, however you can only get their seeds from the Spring Egg Festival.
- Rhubarb, which is bought from Sandy in the desert only at $9.20 a day.
- If you don't want to travel to the desert/wait for the festival, then potatoes are the best, since they yield the third highest profit at $8.30 a day due to the extra potato you can get (25% chance for each potato).

**Summer**

- Blueberries can *potentially* yield $35.00 a day.  To reach this amount, you need to plant them on the first day of summer.  They are harvestable every 4 days once they mature.
- Starfruit at $30.10 a day, but like Rhubarb, you can only buy them from Sandy in the desert.
- Red Cabbage at $17.80 a day if you don't want to wait for blueberries to grow/travel to the desert for seeds.

**Fall**

- Cranberries at $39.00 per day if planted on the first day of fall.  Like blueberries, they can be continuously harvested after 5 days.
- Pumpkin at $16.90 if you don't want to wait for the cranberries.

Note that each dollar amount is by a per crop basis.  So 10 pumpkins would bring in $169 in one day.  This is also strictly based off of crops alone and the base quality of them.  Higher quality items will increase the amount per day.

Comment: Not necessarily wrong, but me being picky, it's G (Gold) in the game, not $ (Dollars)

Comment: @n_palum Actually, I vaguely recall an NPC referring to money as Gil... though I may be mixing up my games.

Comment: @MageXy Really? I guess I was assuming gold, since it seems to only ever use the G or g. But Gil is a character - he's the guy in the rocking chair in the Adventurer's guild.

Comment: [The Wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Gold) says its just called gold.  The dollar makes it simple to type in my opinion.

Comment: @n_palum Oh perhaps that's what I was thinking of. I think I might've confused it with the Final Fantasy version of money.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Gonna have a hard time to chose the accepted answer...

Comment: that list is a bit out of date, might want to include some of the other crops like coffee

Answer (score 10):

This depends largely on how intense you want to get. Do you want a full, number crunched answer? There are lots of tools out there that you can use to calculate your profits based on starting resources. [This one](https://thorinair.github.io/Stardew-Profits/) is pretty popular, as it shows results in a graph and allows you to specify how much space and money you're willing to invest. There's also [the one I use](http://codepen.io/Pauan/full/ZBjLEp), which shows what crops to plant on what day in order to get the most out of your current resources.

However, if you're just looking for a simple, no-thinking-required answer, the best crops to get per season are as follows (based purely on a profit/day or profit/month value, which is not always the best measure of investment):

- **Spring:** Strawberries provide the best profit per month if you can plant it at the start of the month, but Rhubarb (purchased from the Oasis in the desert) and Cauliflower are the best profit per day.
- **Summer:** Blueberries are absolutely the best crop to plant, having the best profit per month and per day. Starfruit is second best, with Red Cabbage trailing not too far behind.
- **Fall:** Rare Seeds (bought from the Traveling merchant) provide a massive profit (both per month and per day), but chances are you don't have many of them since they are hard to come by - even harder than ancient fruit. Cranberries are also extremely good on a per month basis. In third place is Yams or Artichokes.
- **Winter:** You can't grow anything in winter other than the winter forage seeds, so the choice is pretty easy here, don't you think? :)

In my opinion, if you have enough seeds and a greenhouse, the absolute best profit maker is the ancient fruit seeds. They take a while to collect, but with a seed maker you can quickly fill your entire greenhouse. Combine with a large keg setup (in your shed preferably, though anywhere works), and you can easily make a huge fortune, though it might take a little time.

Comment: I've seen that Melons are technically better per day by a bit, but blueberries are better per month.. maybe just a difference of averages with the number of blueberry drops.

Comment: I tried the rare seed method and its too annoying.  Yes you make a lot off them, and if you make seed makers to get more seeds, you can continue the cycle, but its very slow plus you have to sacrifice the sweet gem berry to make seeds.

Comment: @n_palum Yeah, that's why answering this question is not a simple task. I've learned more about economics and return on investment from this game than I did from my actual economics class.

Comment: @MageXy I just wing it.. I don't put a ton of thought into crops.. Besides mayo and cheese make $$$

Comment: @TimmyJim I fully agree. Since it only produces one fruit per harvest, and it takes an entire season to grow, it can take several years (even in the greenhouse) to get enough fruits to be lucrative. That's why ancient fruits are so much better - still really valuable, but after one month of growing they keep producing more fruits every week.

Comment: I think I'm on like year 4 and I'm still missing the ancient seed artifact and thus still don't have the fruit.  The ancient fruit is my last item needed to ship for crops...

Comment: Wow, those tools are just awesome!

Comment: @TimmyJim Try hunting in the jungle/plant-filled area of the mines. The flying bugs and grubs have a 0.5% chance of dropping the ancient seed artifact. That's how I got mine.

Comment: @TimmyJim I haven't gotten one either still, granted I'm not Year 4 though... And also putting fruit into seed make has a tiny chance for giving ancient seeds instead

Comment: @n_palum Cranberries or Blueberries are great for that because of all the bonus fruit you get. That's how I started my Ancient Fruit farm.

Answer (score 5):

If you go to the [crop section of the wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Crops) you will see a list of every single crop you can grow (some cannot be grown until later in the game as Pierre does not initially sell them). It will list what it sells for, at no star, silver and gold stars, and then below that the gold value/day.

If you have access to other things such as preserve jars and kegs, it changes the value of some crops.

**In general:**

- Spring the most valuable crop/day is Strawberries, so save money and buy a bulk at the Spring Egg Festival.
- Summer is blueberries, they regrow every 4 days.
- Fall are cranberries, but they are every 5 days.

There is also this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RfSAzX_1faWUWPZtcjA4pIE-SdyvZGx706qz7DKZlpE/htmlview?usp=sharing&sle=true) that details the per day value as well as the per month value. Their stat shows melon as a higher per day value than blueberries, but blueberries being better for the month. They also show pumpkins as better per day, but cranberries as better for the month. (Long term value of multi-harvest crops).

**NOTE:** All crops can have skewed numbers based on a variety of things (which can make melons vs blueberries close per day worth for example). Fertilizer usage (do you get gold or no stars) and the numbers of berries dropped per crop are the two biggest factors.