# How are 'flavored' honeys decided and what are their worth?

Tags: stardew-valley

Sparked by [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/301296/which-crops-provide-the-most-daily-profit), and not being able to get a super definitive answer on google, I wanted to ask about honey worth/flavor determination.

I know honey is not the most profitable thing on a farm. But aesthetics.

I wanted to know which flowers for each season provide the best worth to honey. When they are placed in the vicinity of the bee hives, it changes it from wild honey to the "flower name" honey.

Also what makes the honey determine which flower to take after? I've placed a tulip and blue jazz next to a hive (same distance) and it chose to take after the tulip, even though they grew on the same day. I understand this may just be random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off the [Wiki page for Honey](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Honey), it looks like the following flowers for each season that yield the most are:

**Spring**

- Blue Jazz flowers at 200g

**Summer**

- Poppy flowers at 380g

**Fall**

- Fairy Rose flowers at 680g

As @JonK pointed out, the [Bee House Wiki Page](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Bee_House) states:

> When there is more than one type of flower within range, the closest flower takes priority. At equal distance, the most expensive flower takes priority.

You can see from [this link](https://stardew.info/planner/48b4b517-45c6-4152-82ba-db6d0e6a44ed/#) that you can have 110 bee hives be within range of just a few flowers for reference.

Comment: That is a whole lot of bee hives for a few flowers... Seems like it'd get crowded in there

Comment: From the [Bee House](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Bee_House) wiki page: "When there is more than one type of flower within range, the closest flower takes priority. At equal distance, the most expensive flower takes priority. "

Comment: @JonK good find! I'll add that in to my answer.  I wonder why the tulip was used in the OPs case then?

Comment: @JonK So I would understand if one grew before the other, that it took after that one, but if they're supposed to take after the expensive one, maybe I just got unlucky that it picked tulip

Comment: If the cheaper flower grew to maturity first then the Bee House would start its production cycle using that flower

Comment: I'm wondering if planting order matters.  Crops all grow at the same time, but in cases like this, I wonder if the time that the crop is planted is considered.

Comment: @TimmyJim it still wouldn't make sense though, I planted them apart (the jazz first since it takes longer) so that they'd grow on the same day. Maybe by chance the tulip "matured" before the jazz in the morning and it picked that.

Comment: @JonK The bee house doesn't seem to take after the flower until it begins a new cycle, but even after one tulip cycle, it didn't switch to the more expensive flower.